# PHP list all years between two dates

Tags: php, html, css

I created a form that a user needs to fill out.  Based on the age answer, I will need to list all years between the current year and the birth year. I was able to figure out how to convert the age number to an actual year with:

```
function birthday_year($years) {
    return date('Y', strtotime($years . ' years ago'));
}

$byear = birthday_year($age);
echo $byear;
```

I'm having a difficult time listing all the years between the birth year and current year.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  I was able to find other code examples that list months but when I try to manipulate the code to years it doesn't work at all.  Only my 3rd week with PHP, so its still pretty new to me.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you marked it as duplicate. I mentioned in my post that I saw the months code examples but I need one for years and couldn't figure out how to change months to years

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways you could probably handle it, but a rather simple answer would be to loop from the year you've decided on, up to the current year.

```
for ($nYear = $byear; $nYear <= date('Y'); $nYear++) {
        echo $nYear . "\n";
}
```

Reverse the order :

```
for ($nYear = date('Y'); $nYear >= $byear; $nYear--) {
        echo $nYear . "\n";
}
```

Note that your code is wrong to assume that n years ago is the birth year. If you were 9 today (and your birthday was tomorrow) your code would say (today) that you were born in 2006 and tomorrow it would say 2005.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, they don't input a day or month.  They just pick their age number and I convert to a year.  So, it works well for what I need.  Would you know how to reverse the order of the results?  So, instead of saying 1980 to 2015, is there away to have it output current year first(2015....1980)?

Comment: I've posted the reverse. You just initialize at the high end and count down instead.